# Where added objects are stored in ObjectContext?

Tags: entity-framework

Suppose I have an ObjectContext of some sort with Order entities in it. So I can fetch orders from DB with:

```
MyContext.Orders.Select(...);
```

I can create new orders with:

```
Order.CreateOrder(...);
```

And add them to context:

```
MyContext.AddToOrders(newOrder);
```

But when I add new order into context it doesn't show up anywhere. I can't find it in MyContext.Orders, or anywhere else. Though If I invoke SaveChanges I'll be stored in DB successfully.

This must be something very simple I'm missing out here.

Comment: I understand, that once Orders a fetched from DB they're cached inside ObjectContext. The question is: where does ObjectContext stored newly added entities? And is there a place where I can get a list of entities read from DB and ones I've just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyContext.Orders will fetch the orders from the database.

Since your new `Order` object hasn't been added to the database, it won't show up there.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/nilotpal/archive/2009/07/28/to-query-the-local-object-context.aspx). I guess I'll go that way.